# Where should I put pre-loader image on page load?

Tags: javascript, css

I have pre-loader image inside body tag and  nav tag is inside head , nav tags
elements  are remaining on the page, while loader is showing for body
onload only. How to do it properly without using onload in body tag

```
<html>
   <head>
    <style>
      body {
        background-image: url("https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/elegant-white-background-with-shiny-lines_1017-17580.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg"), url("https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/140000/nahled/grey-white-background.jpg");
      }
    </style>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </head>
  <body onload="loader()">
    <div id="loading">
        <img id="loading-image" src="http://people.ischool.berkeley.edu/~ellyrath/images/spinner-loop.gif" alt="Loading..." />
    </div>
    This body has pre-loaded image
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      function loader () { 
        document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
      }
    </script>   
  </body>   
</html>
```

Comment: `nav` tag _does not_ go inside `head`.... it is part of the `body`.... see use for `head` here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/The_head_metadata_in_HTML

Comment: Head and header are different

Answer (score 0):

Please read on what [belongs in the head element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/The_head_metadata_in_HTML) - below I've moved the nav into the body where it belongs.

No need for an `onload` - simply run the javascript line(s) immediately in the script tag.

Alternatively, you could keep it in a function, and immediately call the function in your script.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-image: url("https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/elegant-white-background-with-shiny-lines_1017-17580.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg"), url("https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/140000/nahled/grey-white-background.jpg");
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="loading">
    <img id="loading-image" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
  </div>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  This body has pre-loaded image
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    // simply execute this function immediately...
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well What you want to achieve you can do something like this using jquery

or you can follow this [https://devdojo.com/tutorials/get-a-preloader-on-your-site-with-jquery][1]

```
   <head>
    <style>
      body {
        background-image: url("https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/elegant-white-background-with-shiny-lines_1017-17580.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg"), url("https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/140000/nahled/grey-white-background.jpg");
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    $(window).load(function() {
   $('#loading').fadeOut('slow');
});
  </head>
  <body >
    <div id="loading">
        <img id="loading-image" src="http://people.ischool.berkeley.edu/~ellyrath/images/spinner-loop.gif" alt="Loading..." />
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    This body has pre-loaded image

  </body>   

</html>


  [1]: https://devdojo.com/tutorials/get-a-preloader-on-your-site-with-jquery
```

Comment: Question is not tagged `jQuery` . Also `.load()` shortcut event listener is deprecated. See docs